# A similar hook as wp_head for the admin area

Tags: admin, hooks, admin-bar

I'm adding a node to the toolbar and wish to tweak the css a bit.
I don't have any external CSS files and I'm echoing the CSS using the `wp_head` action hook. Is there a similar action hook that I can use to echo the CSS everywhere? Both front-end and admin area?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The alternative to [`wp_head`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_head/) action in admin area is [`admin_head`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_head/). But, if your CSS depends on another stylesheet, you should use [`wp_add_inline_style()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style) function hooked to [`admin_enqueue_scripts` action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/).

Comment: And is there a single hook that will allow me to echo in both front-end and admin area?

Comment: A hook to echo in `<head>` in both sides ... I don't think so, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to **wp_head** and **admin_head** there's a separate hook for the login screen, called [login_head](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/login_head) if any custom code is needed there.

*( This should have been a comment, but my reputation is still to low. )*

Answer (score 4):

You could always just hook into both of them from the same function:-

```
function wordpress_stackexchange_242372()
{
    // Your code here
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wordpress_stackexchange_242372' );
add_action( 'admin_head', 'wordpress_stackexchange_242372' );
```

Pretty sure that should work :)